# Why do the derivatives become different after rewriting a condition?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

It seems to me as if I overlooked something trivial in the following case. Nonetheless, even after thinking through it for a while, I don't really see the mistake. Maybe you can help me with that...

I have the following condition $cx(w)y(w)-1>0$, with $c,x(w),y(w)>0$

and would be interested whether this condition is easier to fulfil if w changes. Note that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}>0$, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}<0$ and $\frac{\partial c}{\partial w}=0$.

Therefore, $\frac{\partial [c x(w) y(w) - 1]}{\partial w}>0 \leftrightarrow \frac{\partial x}{\partial w}y+x\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}>0$

However, I may also rewrite the first condition $cx(w)y(w)-1>0$ as $cx(w)-y(w)^{-1}>0$ with the derivative $\frac{\partial [c x(w)  - y(w)^{-1}]}{\partial w}>0 \leftrightarrow c\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}-\frac{\partial y^{-1}}{\partial w}>0$

However, this does not make sense to me as now the constant $c$ matters for the derivative even though it does not matter in the first case. Why has my rewriting of the condition changed the derivatives?

Comment: $f>0$ does not imply $f'>0$!

Comment: That is true. What specifically are you referring to?

Comment: you started with $ f>0$ but then started reasoning with $f'>0$ ($f = cx(w)y(w)-1$ and $f' = \partial f/\partial w$)

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have been more specific... I have the condition that f>0 should be fulfilled. However, I am interested whether f>0 holds much more easily with a change in w and therefore I would like to know whether f'>0. Does this make sense or do I still misunderstand your point?

Comment: Yes I think we are talking about the same thing. (You also need to know $f(0)\ge 0$ (or $f(w_0)$).) What this means is you are getting sufficient conditions, and it is IMO not surprising when  sufficient conditions have "unusual conditions" attached; for instance if I want to show $x>0$, a sufficient condition is that $x>0$ and is say...rational. Since your steps are not reversible, its hard to say if your steps are "optimal". In contrast, if it were true that $f>0$ implied $f'>0$, then I would be very very confused by your results

Comment: I see, thanks! Just to clarify, what steps are not reversible in my question? The only step should be to divide the condition by y(w), which should be reversible.

Comment: The step where you decide to use $f'>0$ to deduce $f>0$ (hence first comment)

Comment: Actually, that's a good point, as I am not intending to do that. Where do I use f'>0 to deduce f>0?

Comment: OK, if you don’t then I guess I did actually misunderstand you in ‘ However, I am interested whether f>0 holds much more easily with a change in w and therefore I would like to know whether f'>0.’ Sorry :/

Comment: Making the division limits the range for the function - it can not be 0. I would expect it to be reflected in the derivative.